# Integral for infinite resistor grid problem

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I'm studying the [infinite grid resistor problem](https://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath668/kmath668.htm), and I've noticed that at some point Mathematica solution diverges with the one that's on the theorical study

$$\frac{1}{i\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{1-e^{i \arccos(2-\cos(\alpha))}\cos(\alpha)}{\sin( \arccos(2-\cos(\alpha)))}d\alpha$$

The problem is that the site gives following answer:

$$\frac{2}{\pi}$$

While Mathematica gives this to me:

$$-\frac{2}{\pi}$$

The sign is the opposite. So I'd like to know what's I didn't understood.

This is the command that I've used for making the integral:

```
R11 = 1/(Pi I) Integrate[(1 - Exp[I (ArcCos[2 - Cos[a]])] Cos[a])/Sin[ArcCos[2 - Cos[a]]], {a, 0, Pi}]
```

I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong and how can I fix it.

Comment: The article you sited is wrong, because the integrand is strictly negative.  By the way, `NIntegrate` gives the same answer as `Integrate` to several significant figures.

Answer (score 1):

The solution starting from the indefinite integral seems to match:

```
indef = 1/(I Pi) FullSimplify[
  Integrate[(1 - Exp[I (ArcCos[2 - Cos[a]])] Cos[a])/Sin[ArcCos[2 - Cos[a]]], a], 
     Assumptions -> {0 <= a <= Pi}];
Limit[indef, a -> Pi] - Limit[indef, a -> 0]
(* -(2/\[Pi]) *)
```

Comment: It works also without the limit, `(indef /. a -> Pi) - (indef /. a -> 0)`. So I'm doing the definite integral in the wrong way?